# Modify an Excel sheet from Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, worksheet-function

Is it possible to open a worksheet in excel from matlab and edit the formulas?  The idea is to automate an uncertainty analysis by creating a second sheet with the uncertainty in each cell for the value from the previous cell.  Essentially, I want to treat the cells as variables and do SQRT(SUM(Partials(xi)^2)) for each cell.  Matlab should have no problem with the calc, but can it edit the formulas in sheets?

The process currently is to copy and paste from excel to matlab.  Here's a small function that does the uncertainty in matlab against on array of equations:

```
function [f_u_total f_u] = uncertAnalysis(f, vars, vars_u)
    f_u = [];
    f_u_total = [];
    for(i=1:length(f))
        f(i)
        item = uncertAnalysisi(f(i), vars, vars_u);
        f_u = [f_u; item(1)];
        f_u_total = [f_u_total; item(1)];
    end
end


function [f_u_total f_u] = uncertAnalysisi(f, vars, vars_u)
    f_u = [];
    % take the partials and square them
    for i=1:length(vars)
        f_u = [f_u; vars(i) (diff(f, vars(i)).*vars_u(i)).^2];
    end
    % calculate the RSS
    f_u_total = (sum(f_u(:,2))).^.5;
end
```

As an aside, the equations look something like this (why I'm not doing this by hand):

```
=(9*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^4/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*F3^2+1/4*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3/(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*O3^2+1/4*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3/(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*P3^2+9*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^4*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*Q3^2+1/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*S3^2+9*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*C!Z3^2/C!U3^2*U3^2+4*C!S3^2/C!V3^6*C!W3*(C!O
3-C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*V3^2+1/4*C!S3^2/C!V3^4/C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*W3^2+1/4*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3^3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*X3^2+9*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^8/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*Y3^2+9*C!S3^2/C!V3^4*C!W3*(C!O3-
C!P3)/C!X3*C!Q3^6*C!F3^6/C!Y3^6/(C!U3^C!Z3)^6*LOG(C!U3)^2*Z3^2)^(1/2)
```

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using Excel for this at all? It's not really intended for scientific data analysis like this. You might be better off exporting the data to text files, importing into MATLAB, calculating your results, then saving as text and importing back into Excel.

Comment: David, its the 'standard' in our lab (mechanical engineering lab).  I agree, and like to keep things purely in matlab if I can.

I must say though, excel does have its merits. For example having the sheet 'programmed' while you take data provides for some nice real-time calculations/visualizations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it through COM/ActiveX/Automation. Look at the [External Interfaces](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brd05nl.html) document; there's an example for how to access Excel documents through Excel's Automation interfaces.

I have next-to-no experience manipulating Excel in this manner, but I know you can do just about anything in Excel through Automation and editing cell formulas doesn't sound that hard.

edit: I can't find a reference to the Excel object model, but here's another example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982

Comment: Thank you jason, this looks promising.  It looks like i could add an extra worksheet to the workbook as well.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/data/1-17PWC.html?solution=1-17PWC for an example.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My previous assumption that [XLSWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) wouldn't work was wrong. I just tried the following in MATLAB:

```
xlswrite('xltest.xls',{'1' '2' '=SUM(A1,B1)'});
```

and when I opened the file in excel, the function was in fact there! The limitation on this would be that you would have to use only the functions that are in Excel.

Unfortunately, I don't believe [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) can read the formulae into MATLAB (it appears to just get the result).

PREVIOUSLY SUGGESTED OPTIONS:

You may want to check out the [Spreadsheet Link EX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/exlink/exlink_product_page.html) software on the MathWorks website, although I'm a bit unfamiliar with it and am not sure if even that can do what you need. Something else that you should look into is [MATLAB Builder EX](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlabxl/), which "lets you integrate MATLAB® applications into your organization's Excel® workbooks as macro functions or add-ins". Sounds promising...

Comment: Seems similar to some XLS reading methods i used in LabView... hm.  Checking out the link, ty

Comment: I think those would definitely work, somewhat of a price barrier though.  If i don't find a free option I think I will go with what's looking like the second one.  ty +1

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a terribly elegant solution, but if you save a new `.xls` spreadsheet that's simply a tab-delimited (or CSV) file, you can have Matlab generate formulas and when Excel opens the document the values will populate.

In Perl, I've handled it something like this:

```
open(OUTPUT,'>tmpfile.xls');
print OUTPUT "1\t2\t=A1+B1\n";
close(OUTPUT);
```

And when `tmpfile.xls` is opened in Excel, cell `C1` will display as 3, which will dynamically update appropriately if `A1` or `B1` are changed.

(I'm not good with Matlab, so I have no knowledge of any sort of plugins)

Comment: to clarify, you can save it as an xls and that will keep the equations and not the values?

Comment: That's correct. It's definitely janky, but Excel will do auto-translation and maintain the formulas. When in doubt, open it and then save it as "real" .xls :) (I feel horrible suggesting this, though)

Comment: lol, 'janky' indeed.  But it might be the easiest way to get the formulas.

Comment: Also, to clarify, there's no real need even to save it as .xls, that's mostly just so that double-click open with Excel will work (in Windows). Excel will open the file regardless of extension, though you may have to specify its encoding.

Comment: Ty kyle, took some 'fedangling' to get it to not save the values.

Comment: Ha, you may have just beat "janky". Strange that it wouldn't go dynamic for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use COM/ActiveX. You can open an Excel instance via the following command:

```
xlApp = COM.Excel.Application;
```

Then use a combination of code completion and the VBA help in Excel itself to work out the rest.

Remember to close Excel with

```
xlApp.Quit;
delete(xlApp);
```

On a side note, so-called CSE (Control-Shift-Enter) formulae may help? See [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel+cse+formula).

Comment: Do you not need something preceeding your first command so as to initiate COM? If you do, what is the command?

Comment: Is that the same as xlApp = actxserver('Excel.Application'); ?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, see the code below (xlswrite) for using ActiveX from Matlab:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2855